# Add pair of values as parameters in a SQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

How can I add pair of values as parameter in a SQL query?

```
Dim insertQuery As String = Teilnehmerkreiszuordnung.CreateInsertSqlStatement(id, addBefugnisseIdList)
Using cn As DbConnection = DbConnection
   Using command As DbCommand = cn.CreateCommand()
      command.CommandText = insertQuery
      // Add values with parameters???
      command.ExecuteNonQuery()
   End Using
End Using
```

CreateInsertSqlStatement function:

```
Public Shared Function CreateInsertSqlStatement(ByVal seminarId As Integer, ByVal addBefugnisseList As List(Of Befugnisse)) As String
   Dim strIns = String.Empty
   Dim insertQuery As String = String.Empty
   If (addBefugnisseList.Any()) Then
      For i = 0 To (addBefugnisseList.Count - 1)
         strIns = strIns + String.Format("({0},{1})", seminarId, addBefugnisseList(i).AutoID)
         If (addBefugnisseList.Count - 1 - i > 0) Then
            strIns = strIns + ","
         End If
      Next
      insertQuery = String.Format("INSERT INTO teilnehmerkreiszuordnung(SeminarID, befugnisID) VALUES {0}", strIns)
   End If
   Return insertQuery
End Function
```

**The Output of the Function is like:**

```
INSERT INTO teilnehmerkreiszuordnung(SeminarID, befugnisID) VALUES (2,5),(2,6),(2,7)
```

Comment: Could you explain what do you expect the query text to be? Or are you just asking how to replace your current string concatenation approach with a parameterized query?

Comment: If I understand, you'll have to use parameters and do 3 insert.

Comment: if `addBefugnisseIdList` contains values to be used, then call to `CreateInsertSqlStatement` is already returning a pre-filled query string. just execute it. But i suggest you to go for a prepared statement to fill the criteria.

Comment: I expect the query text to be "INSERT INTO teilnehmerkreiszuordnung(SeminarID, befugnisID) VALUES (@s2, @b5),(@s2, @b6),(@s2,@b7)"

Comment: I would change the logic to this. I would change the _CreateInsertSqlStatement_ to a _CreateInsertSqlCommand_ and let it create the DbCommand and the parameters while looping over the list. The caller need just to call the ExecuteNonQuery or fix something in the command if required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing your code to a parameterized query is enough simple. But I would change the logic to concentrate the creation of the parameters while you loop over the list. This will avoid a second loop to build the parameters once you get back from the method

```
' pass also the connection and lets return a DbCommand filled with proper parameters'  
Public Shared Function CreateInsertSqlCommand(ByVal DbConnection cn, 
                       ByVal seminarId As Integer, 
                       ByVal addBefugnisseList As List(Of Befugnisse)) As DbCommand

   ' Use a StringBuilder to get better memory footprint with repeated string changes'

   Dim strIns As StringBuilder = new StringBuilder()

   Dim command As DbCommand = Nothing
   Dim insertQuery As String = "INSERT INTO teilnehmerkreiszuordnung(SeminarID, 
befugnisID) VALUES " 
   If (addBefugnisseList.Any()) Then
         'Create the command and add the invarian parameter'
         command As DbCommand = cn.CreateCommand()
         command.Parameters.Add("@s", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = seminarID
         ' loop and add the list parameters while building the parameters placeholders'
         For i = 0 To (addBefugnisseList.Count - 1)
             strIns.AppendFormat($"(@s,@a{i}),")
             command.Parameters.Add($"a{i}", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = addBefugnisseList(i).AutoID
         Next
         ' Remove the last comma'
         if strIns.Length > 0 Then
            strIns.Length = strIns.Length - 1
         End If
         command.CommandText = insertQuery + strIns.ToString()
   End If
   Return command
End Function


Using cn As DbConnection = DbConnection
   Using command As DbCommand = Teilnehmerkreiszuordnung.CreateInsertSqlCommand(cn, id, addBefugnisseIdList)
      if command IsNot Nothing Then
          command.ExecuteNonQuery()
      End If
   End Using
End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   Public Shared Function CreateInsertSqlCommand(ByRef command As DbCommand, ByVal seminarId As Integer, ByVal addBefugnisseList As List(Of Befugnisse)) As Boolean
        Dim IsThereAnyQuery As Boolean = False
        Dim strIns = String.Empty
        Dim insertQuery As String = String.Empty
        If (addBefugnisseList.Any()) Then
            For i = 0 To (addBefugnisseList.Count - 1)
                command.AddParameterWithValue(String.Format("@S{0}", i), seminarId)
                command.AddParameterWithValue(String.Format("@B{0}", i), addBefugnisseList(i).AutoID)
                strIns = strIns + String.Format("(@S{0},@B{1})", i, i)
                If (addBefugnisseList.Count - 1 - i > 0) Then
                    strIns = strIns + ","
                End If
            Next
            insertQuery = String.Format("INSERT INTO teilnehmerkreiszuordnung(SeminarID, befugnisID) VALUES {0}", strIns)
            command.CommandText = insertQuery
            IsThereAnyQuery = True
        End If
        Return IsThereAnyQuery
    End Function
```

Use this method like this:

```
If (Teilnehmerkreiszuordnung.CreateInsertSqlCommand(command, id, addBefugnisseIdList)) Then
     command.ExecuteNonQuery()
End If
```

AddParameterWithValue method:

```
public sealed class DbCommandExtensions
{
    public static void AddParameterWithValue(this DbCommand cmd, string name, object value)
    {
       DbParameter parameter = cmd.CreateParameter();
       parameter.ParameterName = name;
       parameter.Value = RuntimeHelpers.GetObjectValue(value);
       cmd.Parameters.Add((object) parameter);
    }
 }
```